# How to find number string inside delimited string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on this all day and just cannot seem to figure out why it won't work.  I am grabbing a delimited string from a hidden field.  I need to test to see if a string is contained in that original string.  The simple example below should work but does not.

```
var orgStr = "091300159|091409568|092005411";
var newArr = orgStr.split('|');

console.log(orgStr);
console.log(newArr);
console.log("inarray? " + $.inArray(newArr, "092005411"));
```

It seems to work if I can wrap quotes around each value but all attempts are unsuccessful.

Comment: switch the arguments of `$.inArray()`

Comment: `newArr.indexOf('092005411') !== -1`

Answer (score 2):

In JQuery's [inArray function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) the value needs to come before the array.

```
console.log("inarray? " + $.inArray("092005411", newArr));
```

You could also use the native indexOf operator as such:

```
console.log("inarray? " + newArr.indexOf("092005411"));
```

Both should output "inarray? 2" to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) docs.

The first argument is the value and the second the array. You did the opposite.

`$.inArray("092005411", newArr)` correctly returns `2`.